# Multiple filter Searching without having multiple options -ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

[Edited]

I am using ASP.NET MVC with EF 6.
On a Web page which shows all the information regarding customer Name and customer address. Now I want to filter records according to customer name or customer address.
Below is my logic to search the searchText in the customer table and Address Table but still it is only searching by customer Name only.

[image]

```
public class Address
{
    public int AdressID;

    public string Street;
    
    public string city;

    public string Zip;
    
}
```

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId;

    public string CustomerName;
    
    public string AdressId;

    public int CustomerActive;

    public virtual Address Address;
    
    public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites;

}
```

This is what I did in my controller.

```
public AllCustomerList GetCustomersV2WithFilterAsync(FilterQuery fr)
        {
            var searchText = GetFilterForSearchText(fr, FilterType.SearchText);

            this.DatabaseContext.DisableLazyLoading();
            var totalCount = 0;
  
            var customerQuery = this.DatabaseContext.Customers.AsNoTracking().Where(p => 
                                p.customerActive.HasValue && p.customerActive.Value)
                .Include(p => p.Address)
                .Include(p => p.ExternalSystemCustomerIntegrations)
                .Include(p => p.Address1)
                
        
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            {   
               
               //This query will search the string in customer table
                customerQuery = customerQuery.Where(c => c.customerName.Contains(searchText));
                
               
                //In this following code section the searchtext will be queried for customer address and customer Name 
                
                    // searching according to customer Adress
                    customerQuery = customerQuery.Where(c =>
                       c.Address.street.Contains(searchText)
                    || c.Address.street2.Contains(searchText)
                    || c.Address.city.Contains(searchText)
                    || c.Address.County.Contains(searchText)
                    || c.Address.zip.Contains(searchText)
                    );
                
               }
customerQuery = customerQuery.OrderByDescending(p => p.customerID);
                totalCount = customerQuery.Count();
                var customers = customerQuery.GetPaginatedData(fr.Offset, fr.RecordSet, totalCount > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't understand anything, actually...

Comment: In the given Image the search box is searching according to Customer Name Only . Along with it the searchText should also search  in Customer Address or Site Address. If any one or both are found then it should display the respective Customer Address and Customer Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to pay attention to here.

When you build a LINQ query, it is not executed until it is necessary that the data be realised.
Up until that point the query is retained as an expression that can be executed.
You can force the execution of a query in several ways, by `.ToList()` on the end of a query, for example.

The other thing is that in your code, your logic to search address details is after your customer name search. But importantly, **it is just adding to the customer name query**. So in essence you would only find customers when the search text is contained in their name AND part of their address.

You could get around it in a couple of ways.
Either, combine the name and address queries:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
{   
    customerQuery = 
        customerQuery.Where(c => c.customerName.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.street.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.street2.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.city.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.County.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.zip.Contains(searchText));
}
```

Or generate two separate queries:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
{   
    var customerNameQuery = 
        customerQuery.Where(c => c.customerName.Contains(searchText));

    var customerAddressQuery =
        customerQuery.Where(c => c.Address.street.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.street2.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.city.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.County.Contains(searchText)
                              || c.Address.zip.Contains(searchText));

    // ... use the new queries ...
}
```

Comment: I have a question it might silly to you since I am a newbie to .Net :- If we generate separate queries how can we combine the result wrt to customer.

Comment: "your logic to search address details is after your customer name search. But importantly, it is just adding to the customer name query. So in essence you would only find customers when the search text is contained in their name AND part of their address." :-Baiscally I want to have the query that can give me result such that if name doesn't contain the searchText but the address contains it or Vice-Versa or both . I have to store it in the query.

Comment: Replace your query with my first, combined query.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me. Thanks for your time and our knowledge.